# htaccess redirect http://www.example.com to https.example.com

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect my all URL to HTTPS.

HTTP to HTTPS redirect is ok But
http://www.example.com redirects to https://www.example.com then https://example.com. It takes 2 requests. I want to reduce the request to 1

How can I do it directly http://www.example.com to https://example.com?

I tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content/cache/(all|wpfc-mobile-cache)

RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown attempts, could you please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. You need to push your condition to check https above redirection rule; we could handle both conditions(as per your shown urls) in single Rule here.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content/cache/(all|wpfc-mobile-cache) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Not working. It turns into 19 redirection chain

Comment: @MAShuabRatan, Sorry I didn't get it, could you please do elaborate more on this one?

Comment: After using this htaccess rules I checked it in https://www. redirect-checker.org/index.php and the result is 19 redirection(Too many Redirection)

Comment: @MAShuabRatan, do you have any other rules apart from these in your htaccess file?

Comment: @MAShuabRatan, Please make sure to place these Rules at top of your htacces rules file.